# Uniq by object attribute in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, unique

What's the most elegant way to select out objects in an array that are unique with respect to one or more attributes?

These objects are stored in ActiveRecord so using AR's methods would be fine too.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Use [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block:

```
@photos = @photos.uniq { |p| p.album_id }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for [ruby 1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) and later versions.

Comment: +1. And for earlier Rubies, there's always `require 'backports'` :-)

Comment: The hash method is better if you want to group by say album_id while (say) summing up num_plays.

Comment: You can improve it with a to_proc (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc): `@photos.uniq &:album_id`

Comment: @brauliobo for Ruby 1.8 you need to read just below in this same SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/113770/213191

Comment: in a different style, @photos = @photos.uniq(&: album_id)

Answer (score 22):

Add the `uniq_by` method to Array in your project. It works by analogy with `sort_by`. So `uniq_by` is to `uniq` as `sort_by` is to `sort`. Usage:

```
uniq_array = my_array.uniq_by {|obj| obj.id}
```

The implementation:

```
class Array
  def uniq_by(&blk)
    transforms = []
    self.select do |el|
      should_keep = !transforms.include?(t=blk[el])
      transforms << t
      should_keep
    end
  end
end
```

Note that it returns a new array rather than modifying your current one in place. We haven't written a `uniq_by!` method but it should be easy enough if you wanted to.

EDIT: Tribalvibes points out that that implementation is O(n^2). Better would be something like (untested)...

```
class Array
  def uniq_by(&blk)
    transforms = {}
    select do |el|
      t = blk[el]
      should_keep = !transforms[t]
      transforms[t] = true
      should_keep
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice api but that's going to have poor (looks like O(n^2)) scaling performance for large arrays. Could be fixed by making transforms a hashset.

Comment: This answer is out of date.  Ruby >= 1.9 has Array#uniq with a block that does exactly this, as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17):

Do it on the database level:

```
YourModel.find(:all, :group => "status")
```

Comment: and what if it was more than one field, out of interest?

Answer (score 17):

You can use this trick to select unique by several attributes elements from array:

```
@photos = @photos.uniq { |p| [p.album_id, p.author_id] }
```

Comment: so obvious, so Ruby. Just another reason to bless Ruby

Answer (score 6):

I had originally suggested using the `select` method on Array. To wit:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].select{|e| e%2 == 0}`
gives us `[2,4,6]` back.

But if you want the first such object, use `detect`.

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].detect{|e| e>3}` gives us `4`.

I'm not sure what you're going for here, though.

Answer (score 5):

I like jmah's use of a Hash to enforce uniqueness.  Here's a couple more ways to skin that cat:

```
objs.inject({}) {|h,e| h[e.attr]=e; h}.values
```

That's a nice 1-liner, but I suspect this might be a little faster:

```
h = {}
objs.each {|e| h[e.attr]=e}
h.values
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block:

```
objects.uniq {|obj| obj.attribute}
```

Or a more concise approach:

```
objects.uniq(&:attribute)
```

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant way I have found is a spin-off using [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block

```
enumerable_collection.uniq(&:property)
```

…it reads better too!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, I've tackled this problem using the quasi-hacky approach of comparing the Marshaled objects to determine if any attributes vary. The inject at the end of the following code would be an example:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :foo, :bar, :baz

  def initialize(foo,bar,baz)
    @foo = foo
    @bar = bar
    @baz = baz
  end
end

objs = [Foo.new(1,2,3),Foo.new(1,2,3),Foo.new(2,3,4)]

# find objects that are uniq with respect to attributes
objs.inject([]) do |uniqs,obj|
  if uniqs.all? { |e| Marshal.dump(e) != Marshal.dump(obj) }
    uniqs << obj
  end
  uniqs
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hash, which contains only one value for each key:

```
Hash[*recs.map{|ar| [ar[attr],ar]}.flatten].values
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails also has a `#uniq_by` method.

Reference: [Parameterized Array#uniq (i.e., uniq_by)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251871/parameterized-arrayuniq-i-e-uniq-by)

Answer (score 1):

I like jmah and Head's  answers. But do they preserve array order? They might in later versions of ruby since there have been some hash insertion-order-preserving requirements written into the language specification, but here's a similar solution that I like to use that preserves order regardless.

```
h = Set.new
objs.select{|el| h.add?(el.attr)}
```

Answer (score 1):

ActiveSupport implementation:

```
def uniq_by
  hash, array = {}, []
  each { |i| hash[yield(i)] ||= (array << i) }
  array
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Now if you can sort on the attribute values this can be done:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :val
  def initialize(v); self.val = v; end
end

objs = [1,2,6,3,7,7,8,2,8].map{|i| A.new(i)}

objs.sort_by{|a| a.val}.inject([]) do |uniqs, a|
  uniqs << a if uniqs.empty? || a.val != uniqs.last.val
  uniqs
end
```

That's for a 1-attribute unique, but the same thing can be done w/ lexicographical sort ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are not married with arrays, we can also try eliminating duplicates through sets

```
set = Set.new
set << obj1
set << obj2
set.inspect
```

Note that in case of custom objects, we need to override `eql?` and `hash` methods