# Stop duplicates from being added to an array of Ruby objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

how can I eliminate duplicate elements from an array of ruby objects using an attribute of the object to match identical objects.

with an array of basic types I can use a set..

eg.

```
array_list = [1, 3, 4 5, 6, 6]
array_list.to_set 
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

can I adapt this technique to work with object attributes?

thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109781/uniq-by-object-attribute-in-ruby/113770#113770

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can write it into your objects to use `eql?` then you can use `uniq`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are putting the cart before the horse. You are asking yourself: "How can I get `uniq` to remove objects which aren't equal?" But what you *should* be asking yourself, is: "Why aren't those two objects equal, despite the fact that I consider them to be?"

In other words: it seems you are trying to work around the fact that your objects have broken equality semantics, when what you *really* should do is simply *fixing* those broken equality semantics.

Here's an example for a `Product`, where two products are considered equal if they have the same type number:

```
class Product
  def initialize(type_number)
    self.type_number = type_number
  end

  def ==(other)
    type_number == other.type_number
  end

  def eql?(other)
    other.is_a?(self.class) && type_number.eql?(other.type_number)
  end

  def hash
    type_number.hash
  end

  protected

  attr_reader :type_number

  private

  attr_writer :type_number
end

require 'test/unit'
class TestHashEquality < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_that_products_with_equal_type_numbers_are_considered_equal
    assert_equal 2, [Product.new(1), Product.new(2), Product.new(1)].uniq.size
  end
end
```

Comment: Jörg, what if I want to use use `type_number` to consider my products unique for one use, but use a different field, e.g., `color` for another use? Ideally, it'd be nice to be able to use a block much like is common for comparison methods used for sorting. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Ideally I want to prevent an object being added to an array of objects if the has already been added (based on matching attributes). I thought sets might do this.

Answer (score 1):

what about [uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.3/classes/Array.html#M000407)

```
   a = [ "a", "a", "b", "b", "c" ]
   a.uniq   #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

you can use it on object as well!

Comment: He said object attributes, so I'm guessing the complete object won't be identical.

Comment: hi.. beanish is right.. need to match object id for instance... can I pass a block into the to_set or uniq method?

Comment: @Dom: It looks like you can pass a block to `to_set`: http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/to_set. Doesn't show what it does exactly, but I'm guessing it would solve your problem.

Comment: @ryeguy, `*args` and `&block` are just sent to `Set#initialize`

Answer (score 0):

Should you be using an `Array`, or should you be using a `Set` instead? If order isn't important, then the latter will make it more efficient to check for duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for your responses.. uniq works once I added the following to my object model

```
def ==(other)
    other.class == self.class &&
    other.id  == self.id
end
alias :eql? :==
```

Comment: This violates the contract of `Object#hash` and maybe also of `Object#==`.