# How to uniquify an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am aware of "`.uniq`" method but it is not working here. I pushed Mechanize link instances in an array and applied it but it is not removing duplicates. Here is the array..

```
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "2" "/inquiry/inquiry-results.jsp?d-16544-p=2&middleName=&firstName=&lastName=JOHN">,
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "3" "/inquiry/inquiry-results.jsp?d-16544-p=3&middleName=&firstName=&lastName=JOHN">,
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "4" "/inquiry/inquiry-results.jsp?d-16544-p=4&middleName=&firstName=&lastName=JOHN">,
......................................................................................
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "2" "/inquiry/inquiry-results.jsp?d-16544-p=2&middleName=&firstName=&lastName=JOHN">,
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "3" "/inquiry/inquiry-results.jsp?d-16544-p=3&middleName=&firstName=&lastName=JOHN">,
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "4" "/inquiry/inquiry-results.jsp?d-16544-p=4&middleName=&firstName=&lastName=JOHN">,
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "5" "/inquiry/inquiry-results.jsp?d-16544-p=5&middleName=&firstName=&lastName=JOHN">,
#<Mechanize::Page::Link "6" "/inquiry/inquiry-results.jsp?d-16544-p=6&middleName=&firstName=&lastName=JOHN">,
```

but still after using ."`.uniq`" result is same. Here is the ruby code I am using..

```
page.links.each {|link| 
    page_links.push link if link.href =~ /inquiry-results/i and link.text =~ /[0-9]+/
}
```

Comment: That post is related to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109781/uniq-by-object-attribute-in-ruby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Array#uniq` uses the `hash` and `eql?` methods of objects. Make sure these are defined correctly for your objects, or else use `uniq_by` with your criteria.