# find duplicates in each array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, unique, distinct-values

---

**<% @sp_references.each do |sp_ref| %>

 <% sp_ref.all_references.each_with_index do |tax_ref, i| %>
  <%if (tax_ref.reference.uniq) && (tax_ref.reference !~ /emend$/i) %>
   <%= tax_ref.reference %>
  <%end%>
 <%end%>
<%end%>**

---

This 'uniq' option to get distinct elements in tax_ref.reference is not working. It shows "undefined method `uniq' for #

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like `tax_ref.reference` is not an array. `uniq` should be called on arrays. Try this instead:

```
<% sp_ref.all_references.keys.uniq.each do |tax_ref| %>
    <%if (tax_ref.reference !~ /emend$/sp_ref.all_references[tax_ref]) %>
        <%= tax_ref.reference %>
    <%end%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is sp_ref.all_references ? It's not a hash (like I thought).

Answer (score 0):

uniq is a method on any enumerable object (arrays). So you can't call it on the reference object of tax_ref.

Instead, you'll want to call it on sp_ref.all_references, like `sp_ref.all_references.uniq.each`

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109781/uniq-by-object-attribute-in-ruby) has some suggestions on filtering out duplicate objects when only an attribute is duplicated (not unique).

Comment: It doesnt extract 'uniq' distinct elements in tax_ref.reference.

Comment: I believe this is because the objects are not duplicate. They have a duplicate attribute that you are perceiving to be duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%arr = Array.new %> <% @sp_references.each do |sp_ref| %> <% sp_ref.all_references.each_with_index do |tax_ref, i| %>  <%if (tax_ref.reference !~ /emend$/i) %>  <% arr.push("#{tax_ref.reference}") %> <%end%>  <%end%>  <%end%> <%= arr.uniq %>
```

It works for me.