# Parameterized Array#uniq (i.e., uniq_by)

Tags: ruby, arrays

What if instead of removing duplicate elements from an array, I want to remove elements that have a specific property in common?

Specifically, I want to remove all strings from an array with duplicate "essences", where essence is defined like this:

```
class String
  def essence
    downcase.gsub('&', 'and').gsub(/[^a-z0-9]/, '')
  end
end
```

I want something like this:

```
['a', 'A', 'b'].uniq_by(&:essence)
# => ['a', 'b'] (or ['A', 'b']; I don't really care)
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activesupport has a [Array#uniq_by](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/uniq_by), and this is the code:

```
class Array
  def uniq_by
    hash, array = {}, []
    each { |i| hash[yield(i)] ||= (array << i) }
    array
  end
end
```

Facets also has a [Enumerable#uniq_by](http://intra.wortundform.de/doc/gems/facets-2.6.0/rdoc/classes/Enumerable.html):

```
module Enumerable    
  def uniq_by
    h = {}
    inject([]) {|a,x| h[yield(x)] ||= a << x}
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Since 1.9.2, [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) (and [`uniq!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21)) takes a block, so no more need for `uniq_by`.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq confirms this.

Comment: Just in case anyone else runs into this problem, ruby 1.9.2p180 unique with block doesn't seem to work as reliably as uniq_by, though I haven't done extensive testing to figure out what is up.

Comment: And available to earlier Rubies with `require 'backports'`.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty way:

```
['a', 'A', 'b'].group_by {|i| i.essence}.values.map(&:first)
```

And some monkey patching:

```
class Array
  def uniq_by(&block)
    group_by(&block).values.map(&:first)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, just wanted to comment that you can actually do `group_by(&:essence)` so that if you wish to update your answer you can!