# What is the lowest memory occupancy object that can be assigned to a variable?

Tags: ruby

I want to create a `hash` but I'm only interested in the `keys`. As a consequence, I want the `values` to have the *smallest memory footprint* possible. What would be the most suitable object to assign?

- `nil` ?
- a very short symbol like `:a` ?
- Something even smaller?

Comment: Are you trying to emulate a set? There is a set in stdlib, you know.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm trying to emulate a `Set` but I need it to be a `Hash`.

Comment: Can I ask why such a strange requirement?

Comment: Sure. See the response from @DigitalRoss: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731230/different-occurrences-of-a-specific-key-in-an-array-of-hashes/14731255#14731255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following applies to the official Ruby implementation. Other implementations may differ in this regard.

`nil`, `true`, `false` and `Fixnum`s are encoded inside the pointer at the C level, whereas all other objects would involve a pointer that actually points somewhere (so you'd have the space consumption of the pointer plus the space it points to). So these objects are the ones with the smallest memory footprint.

Of these, `nil` makes the most sense semantically.

Comment: I believe your answer to be misleading. See mine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use any value you want, as long as you use the same one.

```
x = "A string value"
h =  Hash[ 10000.times.map{|i| [i, x]} ]
h2 = Hash[ 10000.times.map{|i| [i, nil]} ]
# h takes the same memory as h2
```

In the above example, `x` can be anything you like. The values will only hold the pointer to `x`, or the value itself if `x` is an immediate value (`nil`, `true`, `false` or a `Fixnum`).

**In either case, the memory used is the same!** It will be the size of a pointer on your platform (i.e. `0.size` bytes). In the C code, this corresponds to a `VALUE`.

Just be careful to reuse the same object (i.e. same `object_id`) and not create a new object everytime. For example:

```
h3 =  Hash[ 10000.times.map{|i| [i, "A string value"]} ]
# => h3 will take a lot more space!
h.values.map(&:object_id).uniq.size  # => 1
h3.values.map(&:object_id).uniq.size # => 10000
```

In short, a surefire way is to use `false`, `true`, `nil`, a `Fixnum` or a `Symbol`, since symbols are stored in a global table. `:hello.object_id` is the same everywhere and the string `'hello'` is stored only once and shared for all the `:hello` symbols in your code.

```
h4 =  Hash[ 10000.times.map{|i| [i, :some_symbol]} ]
# => h4 will only take as much space as h and h2
h4.values.map(&:object_id).uniq.size # => 1
```

FYI, the built-in library `Set` has the same requirement, i.e. it uses a `Hash` only for the keys. It uses `true` as the value, for simplicity's sake.

Comment: +1 That is a very good explanation too, thanks. But according to @sepp2k the footprint of storing a pointer to `x` is somewhat bigger than storing `nil` or `true` and this would mean that h2 > h right?

Comment: @sepp2k's answer is misleading. A pointer takes the same memory as `nil` or `true`, at least in MRI.

Comment: I was thinking to assign this as the correct answer but the question is what is the smallest footprint to assign to a variable. And in reality if you use something different from `nil`, `true`or `false`, you still have to store the pointer value or the variable value somewhere. The difference is minimal though.

Comment: @joscas: Unless that object already exists, like a Class, some constant (say `Float::INFINITY`), etc... The understanding is what's important. In any case, there is no reason to worry about the couple of bytes that `:some_symbol` takes!